# express/mongoose update query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I having problem wrapping my head around updating multiple values in my mongoDB using mongooseJS and ExpressJS.

Let say I submit an array of 2 or more objects from my frontend to "express routing" and there I get the req.body parameters to fetch it. My req.body looks like this:

```
[articles:
  { article: { 
       _id: '564209c66c23d5d20c37bd84',
       quantity: 25,
  },
  { article: { 
       _id: '564209c66c23d5d20c37bd83',
       quantity: 51,
  },
}]
```

I then need to loop? to find the specific article in the db to update and when that article is found I want to update the "quantity" value from the frontend to the correct article in db.

```
var id   = [];
var body = {};

for (var i = req.body.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  id.push(req.body[i].article._id);
  body[i] = req.body[i].article.quantity;
};

Articles.update( 
  { _id: {$in: id} }, 
  { $set: {quantity: body[0].article.quantity} }, 
  {multi: true}, 
  function(err, response){
    if(err)
      console.log(err);

  console.log(response);
});
```

The problem with this code is that I put in the first quantity value for all articles and I want it to be the correct one from the frontend. It feels like I'm on the right path but i pretty new to mongoDB and express so if there is a better solution or even a solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Grahlie,

If you are having issues with queries, it's sometimes useful to test queries from the mongodb shell itself to workout the logic.

If your article documents are structured as such:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("564209c66c23d5d20c37bd84"),
  quantity: 25
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("564209c66c23d5d20c37bd83"),
  quantity: 51
}
```

If you want to update the quantity of a unique document based on it's `_id` then you could so with this query.

```
db.articles.update(
   {"_id": "564209c66c23d5d20c37bd84"},
   {$set : { "quantity" : 25}}
)
```

If you wanted to update multiple documents with the same quantity you could use `$in`, but that's not what you want to do. You want to loop through your `req.body` array and update the quantity of each `article`.

So your code would be as such:

```
var articles = req.body;


var updateArticle = function(article) {

    Articles.update(
        {_id:article._id},
        {$set:{ quantity: article.quantity}},
        function(err, article){
            ...
    );

}


for(var i = 0, n = articles.length; i < n; i++){
    updateArticle(articles.[i].article);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this what I was looking for! But have on smaller problem with this, I get this error from node:
throw new Error('cant set header after they are sent');

Im using res.json() function to send back a response and I understand that this is the problem right? Is there a way to collect all responses and send or how should I do this?

Comment: Yes. It's because you are calling res.json() twice.

Comment: You can use [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async#asyncjs) to find out when all of the updates are done and then send your res.json() response.